# Laravel post data from table in view blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel and trying to post data from html "table" "td" to controller, is there any other ways to do it like this "../Student_Edit.php?nomatrik={{data.matrix_no}}"?

This is from my previous project that use php only, but now i want to do something similar in laravel without using any form:

```
<td>{{data.room_no}}</td>
<td><a  href="../Student_Edit.php?nomatrik={{data.matrix_no}}">Edit</a></td>
<td><a  href="DeleteStudent.php?nomatrik={{data.matrix_no}}">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Your laravel routes should not have `.php` in them. Be sure to read up on [Laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing)

Comment: yes, i know that. the code above is from my other project that is not using laravel. but now i want to make something like that in laravel without using form

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using javascript framework. This has nothing to do with PHP.

For Vue.Js like this:

```
<a :href="'/DeleteStudent.php?nomatrik=' + data.matrix_no">
```